# Modulu vs if statement in a loop

Tags: c++, c

I have a loop like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    result[i / 8] = SETBIT(result[i / 8], ++(*bitIndex), array[i]);
    *bitIndex %= 8;
}
```

I wonder what is better, performance-wise, if I use the above style, or this style:

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    result[i / 8] = SETBIT(result[i / 8], ++(*bitIndex), array[i]);
    if(*bitIndex == 8) *bitIndex = 0;
}
```

This is in C, compiled with GCC, an explanation would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: Measure. Optimize. Measure. Any answer to this will be dependent on the version of the compiler and its optimization settings. And the next release might make the answer invalid.

Comment: and instead of dividing by 8, you can use:

    i >> 3;

it is not slower than i/8, but may be faster depending on the compiler options, etc

Comment: you can also try `*bitIndex &= 7;`

Comment: ...and unless you *know* that you have a performance *problem* due to that very line, you should probably chose the most *readable* variant anyway.

Comment: First of all result[i / 8] it is already bad. You will reassign value  same index many times because 1/8 = 0; 2/8 = 0; 3/8 = 0

Comment: @Kirilodius Read the rest of that line too. It's supposed to set the next bit **within the same byte.**

Comment: @glezmen, `8` is a constant, so the compiler should  know that `i/8` and `i>>3` are equivalent (for positive values) so if it doesn't already generate the optimal code get a better compiler, don't obfuscate the code.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant So it even worth because you should to avoid this overindexing. We can see the part of method that just set value to the result[index] and only array[i] is really important here. So it should looks like

`size_t array_index = 0;
    for (size_t r_index = 0; r_index < r_size; ++r_index){
       array_element_type value = 0;
       for (size_t bit_index = 0; bit_index < 8 && array_index < array_size; ++bit_index, ++array_index){
       value = SETBIT(value , bit_index, array[array_index]);
    }
     
       result[r_index] = value;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty, there will only be a fraction of a second difference between them. But I believe the first would be SLIGHTLY better for simple READING style. However, this question references performance in which I still think the first would have the EVER SO SLIGHT edge for the fact the compiler is reading/computing less info.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make any sense to talk about optimization...

- without a specific target system in mind
- before you have ensured that all compiler optimizations are enabled and work
- before you have performed some kind of benchmarking

In your case, for most systems, there will be no difference between the two examples. What you really should focus on is to write readable code, instead of doing the opposite. Consider rewriting your program into something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    (*bitIndex)++;
    SETBIT(&result[i / 8], *bitIndex, array[i]);
    *bitIndex %= 8;
}
```

This will likely yield exactly the same binary executable as to what you already had, +- a few CPU ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why `bitIndex` is a pointer.  But, assuming that `bitIndex` is a parameter to the function containing the given loop, I would pull the `*bitIndex` stuff out of the loop, so:

```
  unsigned bi = *bitIndex ;

  for(i = 0 ; i < arrayLength ; i++)
    {
      result[i / 8] = SETBIT(&result[i / 8], ++bi, array[i]) ;
      bi %= 8 ;
    } ;

   *bitIndex = bi ;
```

[I assume that the `++bi` is correct, and that `SETBIT()` requires 1..8, where `bi` is 0..7.]

As noted elsewhere, the compiler has the `% 8` for breakfast and replaces it by `& 0x7` (for unsigned, but not for signed).  With gcc -O2, the above produced a loop of 48 bytes of code (15 instructions).  Fiddling with `*bitIndex` in the loop was 50 bytes of code (16 instructions), including a read and two writes of `*bitIndex`.

How much actual difference this makes is anybody's guess... it could be that the memory read and writes are completely subsumed by the rest of the loop.

If `bitIndex` is a pointer to a local variable, then the compiler will pull the value into a register for the duration of the loop all on its own -- so it thinks it's worth doing !